# AngularJS module doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, module

So I've been looking at this for way too long. Really hope someone could help me out :) I'm just trying to create a module that creates a directive and controller for my site header in AngularJS. I don't get any error and the log in my code won't show up. This is the code related to the header module:

**header/header.js**

```
 'use strict';
angular.module('myApp.header', [])

.directive("headerBar", [function(){
  return {
    restric: "E",
    templateUrl: "header/header.html",
    controller: 'HeaderCtrl'
  };
}])

.controller('HeaderCtrl', ['$log', function($log) {
  $log.log('test header controller');
}]);
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.header'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="header/header.js"></script>


<header-bar></header-bar>
```

Comment: Have you initialized the app ?

Comment: Why would I add an object-related directive to my main module? And yes, I initialized the app, the routing modules work perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a typo on your directive definition:

- Should be `restrict: "E"`, you're currently missing the 't'

Comment: Hi, totally overlooked that. Thanks for noticing! For the other possible reasons you had mentioned before (and the other answers): In the original post I said that I only posted the code related to the issue, so all my includes and so on were already there. But again, thanks for the quick help. It works!

Comment: I noticed that after re-reading, so I edited my post to remove all those other points. Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `app.js` and `angular.js` reference scripts in your index page

Some think like below

```
   //Jquery Scripts
   //Angular.js library scripts 
  <script src="header/header.js"></script>
  **<script src="app.js"></script>**// Please refer here your app.js script



<header-bar></header-bar>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.Please check that you are including all files.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="header/header.js"></script> 
        <script src="app.js"></script> 
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp.header" ng-controller="HeaderCtrl">
<header-bar></header-bar>

</body>
</html>
```